# Flying Saucer - first page different than other pages

Tags: javascript, jsf, flying-saucer

I´m currently developing a **JSF document designer** for design the template for offers, invoices etc.
With my designer I can drag and drop different components into my JSF page (like positiontable, company logo etc.). This is already working and I can generate the PDF from my JSF page.
What I´m trying to do is now the following:
- I can define in my JSF page two different pages:
  a) First page
  b) all other pages

Why?
- On first page I need e.g. "project infos" or "customer info", which I don´t need on the other pages. Therefore I have the possibility in my designer to design:
a) First page
b) All other pages

The challenge is now:
- On First page I can have a table, which is not only for one page, it will be also on second page and so on. But I want to have on the first page really only the design for the first page and all other pages have than the design for "all other pages".

Is there any idea how this can be done?
- How can I define this content should be visible on **page1**
- How can I define this content should be visible on the **other pages**?
- If I have a datatable on page1 and it´s longer than one page, how can I ensure on the second page the columns from the datatable are not repeated again in page2, 3, 4...?

Comment: Did you plan to add a [mcve]? I'm not yet able to understand the pure JSF related part of your challenge. To me code combined with short description of expected/observed behaviour is more speaking than any well written text wall would ever be.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I can understand it, but it´s a huge project, so I cannot share only a short snipped of code...What did you not understand?

Comment: It starts on the terms `first page`, `second page`, `other pages`, `page1, 2, ...`. Here already I'm unsure if this is about a paginated dataTable or multiple separate xhtml views or a mix of both. I'm not asking for code from your product, but creating [mcve] mostly involves having a tiny additional JSF project to test/reproduce/demonstrate stuff that does not neessarily include productive code.

Comment: I have good knowledge on flyingsaucer and this is not JSF related but how printed tables repeat their column headers on additional printed pages since that is common to do. If you create a plain html table and 'flying-saucer' that, you'd have the same problem. Doing that is creating a [mcve]. CSS3 comes to the resque here.